# GitLab LDAP scondary strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, omniauth, gitlab

I'm using GitLab CE Omnibus package (gitlab_7.7.2-omnibus.5.4.2.ci-1_amd64) on a clean Debian (debian-7.8.0-amd64) installation.

I followed the installation process on https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/ and everything works fine.

I modified /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb to use a single LDAP server for authentification.
Which worked also as expected.

But when I tried to use a secondary LDAP connection "gitlab-ctl reconfigure" gives me the output:

```
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: rake aborted!
Devise::OmniAuth::StrategyNotFound: Could not find a strategy with name `Ldapsecondary'. Please ensure it is required or explicitly set it using the :strategy_class option                          .
Tasks: TOP => cache:clear => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear ----
```

So, the problem is that I can use the LDAP connection 'main' but I cannot use the connection 'secondary'.

**Is there any possibility to use two different LDAP connection in the CE edition at once?**

I'm new to ruby [on rails]. I found something in /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/ldap/config.rb but I'm not able to debug anything.

Here are my settings in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
  main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
    label: 'First Company'
    host: '192.168.100.1'
    port: 389
    uid: 'sAMAccountName'
    method: 'tls' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
    bind_dn: 'debian@firstcompany.local'
    password: 'Passw0rd'
    active_directory: true
    allow_username_or_email_login: false
    base: 'dc=firstcompany,dc=local'
    user_filter: '(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))'
    ## EE only
    group_base: ''
    admin_group: ''
    sync_ssh_keys: false

  secondary: # 'secondary' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of second LDAP server
    label: 'Second Company'
    host: '192.168.200.1'
    port: 389
    uid: 'sAMAccountName'
    method: 'tls' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
    bind_dn: 'debian@secondcompany.local'
    password: 'Passw0rd'
    active_directory: true
    allow_username_or_email_login: false
    base: 'dc=secondcompany,dc=local'
    user_filter: '(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))'
    ## EE only
    group_base: ''
    admin_group: ''
    sync_ssh_keys: false
EOS
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple LDAP servers is an EE feature so setting the config in CE won't do anything. You can see the feature [in GitLab documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/integration/ldap.html#integrate-gitlab-with-more-than-one-ldap-server-enterprise-edition%20in%20the%20GitLab%20documentation).

Answer (score 0):

With [GitLab 14.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/01/22/gitlab-14-7-released/#ldap-failover-support) (January 2022, seven years later), this is now possible! (for hosted instances)

> ### LDAP failover support
>
> You can now specify multiple hosts (using `hosts`) in your GitLab LDAP configuration.
>
> GitLab will use the first reachable host. This ensures continuity of access to GitLab should one of your LDAP hosts become unresponsive.
>
> Thanks to [Mathieu Parent](https://gitlab.com/sathieu) for the contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/index.html#basic-configuration-settings) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/139).